# How to call the "host" and "sender" of an embassy?

Tags: word-request

Let's say Algeria builds an embassy in Benin.

When speaking about this embassy,

- How to call Algeria? (the country that runs the embassy and has the staff)
- How to call Benin? (the country in which the embassy in built)

I am creating a table which has these "host" and "sender" columns, for each embassy of the world. A better, yet short and unambiguous name would be great. Other columns will be Address/Phone/etc.

Comment: **Host** and **Representing** should be clear enough.

Comment: @JoeDark: Thanks! Could you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is clear:

> Represented: Algeria
>
> Host: Benin